# existence of a particular first-order sentence

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

> A sentence is a first-order formula without any free variables. Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of first-order sentences such that $A\cup B$ is unsatisfiable (i.e. there does not exist a valuation that satisfies it). Prove that there exists a first-order sentence $C$ so that

- every model that satisfies $A$ also satisfies $C$ (i.e. $A\vdash C$, and
- every model that satisfies $B$ also satisfies $\neg C$ (i.e. $B\vdash \neg C$).

I think this might relate to the consistency of $A$ and $B$; if a set of sentences $A$ is inconsistent, then there is a set of sentences $C$ so that $A\vdash C$ and $A\vdash \neg C$ (i.e. $A\vdash \perp$). Since $A\cup B$ is unsatisfiable, it seems this can be shown, but I can only conclude that there exists a set of sentences $C$ so that $A\cup B \vdash C$ and $A\cup B\vdash \neg C.$ It also seems that I may need to prove that unsatisfiability implies inconsistency.

Comment: This follows easily from the Compactness Theorem.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thanks, but can you elaborate further? The compactness theorem states that a set of sentences has a model iff every finite subset of that set has a model. How is that useful in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if you or a moderator undeleted your question - but just FYI, it's considered bad form to delete your own question after receiving an answer. Even if it's no longer useful to you, the  question and answer may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A\cup B$ is unsatisfiable. By the compactness theorem, there are finitely many sentences $A_1,\dots,A_n\in A$ and $B_1,\dots,B_m\in B$ such that $\{A_1,\dots,A_n,B_1,\dots,B_m\}$ is unsatisfiable. Let $C = \bigwedge_{i=1}^n A_i$ (and note that $C = \lnot \left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^m B_i\right)$ would work just as well).

Topologically, this exercise says that in the Stone space of complete $L$-theories, any two disjoint closed sets are separated by a clopen set and its complement.